# Finding remaining eigenvector

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a Matrix *$U$* = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  0 & 3 & 0 & 4 \\
  0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}

I have found the eigenvalue of the matrix is $1$, and I try to find the basis for *$(U-I)$*.

So far, I have found the Eigenspace 1 is (row reduced)

\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}

By back substitute the matrix, I have span
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0  \\
  -2 \\
  0  \\
  1  
\end{pmatrix}

However the answer has one other vector with
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1  \\
  0  \\
  0  \\
  0  
\end{pmatrix}

I would like to know how to find the vector above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row echelon form has leading $1$'s in columns $2$ and $3$, so the variables $x_1$ and $x_4$ corresponding to the other two columns are arbitrary.  The nonzero rows correspond to equations
$$ \eqalign{x_2 + 2 x_4 &= 0\cr
             x_3 &= 0\cr} $$
The general solution is thus
$$\pmatrix{x_1 \cr -2 x_4 \cr 0\cr x_4}
$$
With $x_1 = 1$ and $x_4 = 0$ you get vector
$$ \pmatrix{1 \cr 0 \cr 0\cr 0\cr}$$
and with $x_1 = 0$ and $x_4 = 1$ you get $$\pmatrix{0\cr -2  \cr 0\cr  1\cr}$$

Answer (score 0):

$HINT$: It is always better to know the number of linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to an eigenvalue before actually finding them, and that is equal to $n-r$, where $r=$Rank of matrix $U-tI$ ($t=1$ in your case) and $n=$number of columns on $U$.